# Why does iterable pointer become NULL?

Tags: c, pointers

In this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct iter_obj
{
    void *iterable;
};

#define new_iter_obj(iter) {iter}

void *array_item(int index, void *iterable)
{   
    if (index < 10)
    {
        return (void *) &(((int *) iterable)[index]);
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

void iterate(struct iter_obj *obj)
{
    void *tmp;
    int index = 0;

    while ((tmp = array_item(index, obj->iterable)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *((int *) tmp));
        index++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int countdown[10] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    struct iter_obj cd_iter = new_iter_obj((void *) countdown);

    iterate(&cd_iter);
}
```

The output should be:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

**But:** there is no output.

The thing is, the countdown array in `main` and the `iterable` argument to `array_item` should be equal - and yet `iterable` ends up being NULL (I found this through sprinkling debugging macros through my code *and* using a proper debugger. I don't find any wrong with my code when I debug -- it seems as if this is pretty much random.

If I change the code so that I'm passing `iterable` directly instead of through a struct, the pointer stays the same (correct output).

Why is that? Is it part of C99, is lcc buggy, or what?

I'm using lcc-win32 3.8 (C99) on Windows 8.1.

## New Update

I have found that my code works correctly in Pelles C 8.00 RC1.

Comment: Why not just step through the code in your debugger to see what's really going on ?

Comment: You may consider debugging the contents of the `struct iter_obj` member: `debug_local_var(whatever->iterable, void*, "%p");`

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://ideone.com/QvRwjn

Comment: I've just compiled and run your code. It run fine and "iterable" was not null. I use linux and gcc 4.7, so maybe problem is in your compiler?

Comment: I ran the code in a debugger too. Since it runs fine in other compilers, I'll check if it's just my compiler.

Comment: You say that "`iterable` ends up being NULL", but your program has no code that explicitly prints a message when that occurs. What is the output of your program?

Comment: @KeithThompson What is _supposed_ to happen is that I loop over the `countdown` array using the `iterate` function. Through use of the `array_item` function and a for loop, `iterate` ends up printing the numbers from 10 to 1 backwards.

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the exact output of your program into the question. That's far more useful than your interpretation of what you think it's doing internally. When I run it, it prints the numbers `10` to `1`, in reverse order, one per line, which is exactly what I'd expect -- and `iterable` is never, as far as I can tell, a null pointer.

Comment: @KeithThompson What I'm trying to say is that when I used lcc on my computer, there was no output, and when I debugged the program on my computer, I saw that the `iterable` pointer would become `NULL`.

Comment: Then say that in the question. As it stands, readers have no way of knowing why you think `iterable` is null. And program output is more important than what the debugger tells you; they're could be a bug in the debugger, or you might be interpreting it's output incorrectly. Program output is unambiguous.

Comment: @KeithThompson Are my newest edits good, or are there still ways I can clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You should get a new compiler.

Your compiler will fail to compile the below code correctly. The assertion should be held, but lcc has `cd_iter.iterable == NULL`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct iter_obj
{
    int *iterable;
};

int main()
{
    int countdown[] = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    struct iter_obj cd_iter = { countdown };

    assert(cd_iter.iterable == countdown);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only possible solution I can come up with is to update your compiler or get a new one.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was edited; it was originally clear, concise and correct.